# Difference between 'ctx' and 'self' in python?

Tags: python, pytorch

While using the deep learning library PyTorch I came across definitions like this. Does `ctx` have the same behavior as `self`?

```
class LinearFunction(Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input, weight, bias=None):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weight, bias)
        output = input.mm(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(output)
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, weight, bias = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_input = grad_weight = grad_bias = None
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
            grad_input = grad_output.mm(weight)
        if ctx.needs_input_grad[1]:
            grad_weight = grad_output.t().mm(input)
        if bias is not None and ctx.needs_input_grad[2]:
            grad_bias = grad_output.sum(0).squeeze(0)

        return grad_input, grad_weight, grad_bias
```

Comment: Staticmethods don't refer to `self` at all. They are *staitc*. In other words, they're used as if they are functions defined outside the class. `ctx` is passed explicitly to these methods. It has no relation to `self` at all.

Comment: I presume `ctx` is short for `context` in some fashion.

Answer (score 9):

**A static method (`@staticmethod`) is called using the class *type* directly, not an *instance* of this class:**

```
LinearFunction.backward(x, y)
```

Since you have no instance, it does not make sense to use `self` in a static method.

Here, **`ctx` is just a regular argument** that you'll have to pass when calling your methods.

Answer (score 1):

The `@staticmethod` is a function [decorator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator).

From the docs:

> A static method does not receive an implicit first argument. When function decorated with @staticmethod is called, we don’t pass an instance of the class to it (as we normally do with methods). This means we can put a function inside a class but we can’t access the instance of that class (this is useful when your method does not use the instance).

When you need a utility function that doesn't access any properties of a class but makes sense that it belongs to the class, you use static functions.

In your example `ctx` is the [parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.Function.forward) and technically the property of self where you can put many tensors.

Note: When you define `torch.nn.Module` define just the `forward()` function, that is not `@staticmethod`. When you define new autograd function you define both the `forward()` and `backward()` functions that are `@staticmethod`.